# Avoid loosing precision with the Binomial Distribution /Bayes?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, approximation, bayes-theorem

So when dealing with the Bayes' Rule and Binomial distributions,  the value $p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ loses precision and becomes 0 when $n$ and $k$ are large(noting that the binomial coefficient can be safely ignored since it cancels out). For example if $n = 500\,,\,k=250\,\,$for  $p= 0.05$  , then my TI-83 calculator returns 0.

I found out about a "fix"  for this using the following expression that replaces $p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$.

$e^{k\,ln \,p + (n-k)ln(1-p)-max_i(kln(p_i) + (n-k)ln(1-p_i)}$

I think the $p_i$ in the expression is suppose to represent any one of prior probabilities. Can anyone explain why this works ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do your calculation with natural logarithms, the expression is $p^k(1-p)^{n-k} = \exp( k \log_e(p)+(n-k)\log_e(1-p) )$ which is the first part of your expression.

This should lead you to $0.05^{250}0.95^{250} \approx 1.49 \times 10^{-331}$.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But what is the bearing of the expression $max_i(kln(p_i) + (n-k)ln(1-p_i)$ ? Is this some form of scaling and for what purpose  ?

Comment: You say you "found a fix" including that expression.  Did you discover it yourself or was it somewhere else? At the moment, it is unclear to me what it is suppose to represent

Comment: I found out about this in one of the end of chapter problems of a text book about Bayesian Statistics. Unfortunately, I can't quite remember the name. Based on what I understand, you are suppose to pick the probability $p_i$ from the prior distribution which should result in highest value for the expression. Since there will be a division by this value, I thought it had a scaling effect, but why do you need to scale it ? This is what I am struggling to understand.